# jquery mobile slide listview

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm creating JQM page of google maps locations. I need that on button/link click or any other event list would slide. It's pretty much like http://indiqo.eu/demos/hotcake/. Is there any nice soliution?

Comment: you want this effect on image slideshow or on page change...??

Comment: i want that list of locations would slide over map content in same page. Like this: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/codefuze/HYjEB/1/) but in content area and should be scrollable.

Comment: At the moment i'm thinking about splitview if there is posibility to hide one of panels. what about this idea?